# User profile picture is not displaying properly on comments with Imagecache

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-comments

I have a Drupal setup, and have created an Imagecache preset for the user profile to create a thumbnail picture.

I have enabled user pictures on node comments, but the picture is not displaying correctly

When I view the source, it shows the correct path being "sites/default/files/pictures" etc but ecause the node path is something like /node/9 the path being output for the picture is incorrect

I could change the comment.tpl file and add in the absolute path, but im not sure if this is the best thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [ImageCache Profiles module](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_profiles)? If not, I'd recommend enabling it. Also, there were some recent improvements to it's detection of what context the user picture is being used, so you may want to try the latest dev release. See nid 760900 for more info.